# how to wordwrap text in tooltip

Tags: c#, winforms

How to wordwrap text that need to be appear in ToolTip

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like it isn't supported directly:

> **How do I word-wrap the Tooltip that is displayed?**
>
> Here is a method using Reflection to
>   achieve this.
>
> ```
> [ DllImport( "user32.dll" ) ] 
> private extern static int SendMessage( IntPtr hwnd, uint msg,
>   int wParam, int lParam); 
>
> object o = typeof( ToolTip ).InvokeMember( "Handle",
>    BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance |
>    BindingFlags.GetProperty, 
>    null, myToolTip, null ); 
> IntPtr hwnd = (IntPtr) o; 
> private const uint TTM_SETMAXTIPWIDTH = 0x418;
> SendMessage( hwnd, TTM_SETMAXTIPWIDTH, 0, 300 );
> ```
>
> Rhett Gong

Comment: The magic number 0x418 here should ideally be defined as a constant with the same name as that used in the corresponding header file Commctrl.h: "private const uint TTM_SETMAXTIPWIDTH = 0x418" - this makes it easier to google for more info.

Comment: In Windows 7 I experience that this hack only solves the problem when visual styles are disabled in the OS. Any ideas how to solve it that situation?

Comment: 1) The link to the windowsclient.net blog is invalid. 2) You need `System.Runtime.InteropServices` for the `DllImport` 3) Run the code after instancing the ToolTip object.

Answer (score 4):

Another way, is to create a regexp that wraps automatically.

```
WrappedMessage := RegExReplace(LongMessage,"(.{50}\s)","$1`n")
```

[link](http://www.autohotkey.com/forum/topic18307.html)

Comment: This looks like a PHP code or something.  Here's the c# version:

Regex rgx = new Regex("(.{50}\\s)");

string WrappedMessage = rgx.Replace(longMessage,"$1\n");

Answer (score 1):

You can set the size of the tooltip using `e.ToolTipSize` property, this will force word wrapping:

```
public class CustomToolTip : ToolTip
{
    public CustomToolTip () : base()
    {
        this.Popup += new PopupEventHandler(this.OnPopup);
    }

    private void OnPopup(object sender, PopupEventArgs e) 
    {
        // Set custom size of the tooltip
        e.ToolTipSize = new Size(200, 100);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a piece I wrote recently, I know its not the best but it works. You need to extend the ToolTip Control as follows:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Windows.Forms;

public class CToolTip : ToolTip
{
   protected Int32 LengthWrap { get; private set; }
   protected Control Parent { get; private set; }
   public CToolTip(Control parent, int length)
      : base()
   {
    this.Parent = parent;
    this.LengthWrap = length;
   }

   public String finalText = "";
   public void Text(string text)
   {
      var tText = text.Split(' ');
      string rText = "";

      for (int i = 0; i < tText.Length; i++)
      {
         if (rText.Length < LengthWrap)
         {
           rText += tText[i] + " ";
         }
         else
         {
             finalText += rText + "\n";
             rText = tText[i] + " ";
         }

         if (tText.Length == i+1)
         {
             finalText += rText;
         }
      }
  }
      base.SetToolTip(Parent, finalText);
  }
}
```

And you will use it like:

```
CToolTip info = new CToolTip(Control,LengthWrap);
         info.Text("It looks like it isn't supported directly. There is a workaround at
         http://windowsclient.net/blogs/faqs/archive/2006/05/26/how-do-i-word-wrap-the-
         tooltip-that-  is-displayed.aspx:");
```

Answer (score 0):

For WPF, you can use the TextWrapping property:

```
<ToolTip>
    <TextBlock Width="200" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Some text" />
</ToolTip>
```